# Passing an array by reference shows different values while received at C function

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I am writing a unit test where I am calling a C++ library function from C#.

The unit test looks as below:

```
[Fact]
        public void Int_Array_Fixed_InOut()
        {
            var testArray = new[] { 5, 10, 15 };
            var expectedArray = new[] { 10, 15, 20 };           

            Int_Array_Update(ref testArray);

            Assert.True(testArray.SequenceEqual(expectedArray));
        }
```

The C# function declaration is as below:

```
[DllImport("CTest.dll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Int_Array_Update")]
        public static extern void Int_Array_Update(ref int[] param);
```

The C++ header defination:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Int_Array_Update(int param[3]);
```

The C++ implementation:

```
void Int_Array_Update(int param[3])
{
    const int param_size = 3;   
    std::vector<int> c_param(param, param + param_size); // Here the values i=of c_param are 209891664, 533, 2139062328cbut I am expecting 5,10,15
    RandomFunction(c_param);
    std::copy(c_param.begin(), c_param.end(), param);
}
```

If at all I pass the array from C# without the ref keyword, the values are as expected and any change to the array in the C++ function is reflected at the C# caller. The below unit test works fine by just removing the ref keyword in the unit test calling function and the C# function definition.

```
[Fact]
        public void Int_Array_Fixed_InOut()
        {
            var testArray = new[] { 5, 10, 15 };
            var expectedArray = new[] { 10, 15, 20 };           

            Int_Array_Update(testArray);

            Assert.True(testArray.SequenceEqual(expectedArray));
        }
```

The C# function declaration is as below:

```
[DllImport("CTest.dll", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Int_Array_Update")]
        public static extern void Int_Array_Update(int[] param);
```

I am not sure why the ref keyword fails to marshall the array values.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are aware that C++ with given syntax actually accepts a pointer?

Comment: Yes, I did try by changing the signature of C++ function to __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Int_Array_Update(int* param); but this also works only when i do not specify the ref keyword in the C# function.

Comment: According to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshaling) arrays are by default marshalled to pointers to their first element. So the syntax without `ref` is fine. In C++, references are handled similarly to pointers internally (if resolving directly is not possible), so in fact another level of indirection, comparable to a pointer to pointer in given case. I would assume this is pretty similar in C# – and probably there's no appropriate marshalling for such references.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. That is very informative.

Comment: `ref int[]` is the equivalent of C++ `**int` or `*int[]` in other words it's doubly indirected. `ref` is just wrong here